# How can IV give an indication of the markets opinion about a stock when there's no such thing as IV for a stock?

Tags: stocks, options, implied-volatility

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Implied Volatility is for a specific option contract (a specific strike, a direction, and an expiration). So how can there be IV for a stock?

As I understand it, and again, correct me if I'm wrong, IV is the markets assessment that the stock is about 70% likely (1 Standard Deviation) to move (in either direction) by that percent over the next year.

I'm a bit confused as to how that can be for a stock, when all IV's are for options.

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's a sum combination of different expirations and strikes. Implied volatility is tied to the stock price characteristics, options don't operate in a vacuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since near-term at-the-money (ATM) options are generally the most liquid, the listed implied vol for a stock is usually pretty close to the nearest ATM volatility, but there's not a set convention that I'm aware of.

Also note that for most stocks, vol skew (the difference in vol between away-from-the-money and at-the-money options) is relatively small,

> correct me if I'm wrong, IV is the markets assessment that the stock is about 70% likely (1 Standard Deviation) to move (in either direction) by that percent over the next year.

Not *exactly*.  It's an *annualized* standard deviation of the anticipated movements over the time period of the option that it's implied from.  Implied vol for near-term options can be higher or lower than longer-term options, depending on if the market believes that there will be more uncertainty in the short-term.  Also, it's the *bounds* of the expected movement in that time period. so if a stock is at $100 with an implied vol of 30% for 1-year term options, then the market thinks that the stock will be somewhere *between* $70 and $130 after 1 year.  If you look at the implied vol for a 6-month term option, *half* of that vol is the range of expected movement in 6 months.